# Advice on what kind of paint to use on metal fire pit

Tags: painting, fire-pit

[image]

I'm in the process of building this fire pit made of 4x4 angle iron and rebar.  I know I will have to use some kind of hi temperature paint, my questions are what kind of hi temperature paint?  There is engine enamel, hi heat flat and fireplace paint. Which one would would be best suited for my purpose?  Will I have to cure the paint?  I'm sure there will be a few fires that will get hot but most will be mild.  Thank you.

Comment: engine enamel is generally not designed to be directly exposed to flame, they make a "flame proof" paint for exhaust headers and piston domes that would be acceptable

Answer (score 3):

Use "Stove Black" paint:

[image]

Image stolen from internet and not an endorsement for any particular brand.

Comment: Make sure what you get is rated for exterior use.  Black is going to absorb a lot of UV light and will fade quickly if it's not made to be outside.